# Apple Dev Portal is showing other people's and company's provisioning information, not my own?

Tags: app-store-connect

Not sure where to post this, but I can't find any information anywhere and it seems a bit urgent. When I login to Apple's developer site and go into the provisioning portal, there are app ids, devices, certificates, and company names that I do not recognize. I have sent an email to Apple but it could be days before it is seen and this is a serious security issue. I cannot access any of my own data, and it says I am someone else; I cannot logout this other person, and clearing cache and restarting browser doesn't remove this person as the logged-in user. If I click on "app ids" i see yet another person, the logged-in name changes. If I click on Edit Profile, it correctly shows my name. But nothing I can do allows me to actually see any of my own apps that have been published, and I surely wonder if others are able to somehow see my own apps just like I can see theirs.

Anyone know a more urgent place to report this? Is it happening to anyone else, or have you experienced this before?

Comment: This is not a question related to programming, file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: i know but it is serious enough that i figured reaching out to programmers would be a good thing; what if it happened to others? if the dev portal is having major issues, this needs to get resolved asap; who knows who is able to see and change others' provisioning information

Comment: The best place to warn other iOS developers about this issue (in case everyone has it) are the Apple Developer Forums https://devforums.apple.com/community/ios

Comment: a downvote is what I get for revealing a serious security problem in the apple developer site and asking others about it; obviously, the apple developer site is directly related to software development and it seems odd to disuade members from posting and discussing that here

Comment: Got the exact same problem and no call support here in Thailand and no one will work until Monday. If you get some answer from apple please inform me. This considered serious security hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call them. Everytime I've dealt with apple on the phone, I've been treated efficiently and professionally.

The US number is 1 (408) 974-4897.

Find the other numbers here: https://developer.apple.com/contact/phone.php

Comment: thanks. this has been a really surprising realization, that I am able to access other companies' provisioning information.